# smarty strip tags to remove html tags in php

Tags: php, smarty, strip-tags

I have this code. I want to remove html tags in output of smarty.

```
{assign var=keys value=","|explode:$seo_description}
{foreach from=$keys item=labeldes}
{$labeldes|strip_tags}

{/foreach}
```

I use `strip_tags` but this code doesn't work. Tnx

Comment: What exactly do you have in `$labeldes` and what exactly is result after strip_tags in your code?

Comment: {$labeldes|htmlspecialchars_decode|strip_tags} ?

Comment: In what way it doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks @Peca this worked...

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
$string|htmlspecialchars_decode|strip_tags
```

This will decode the special characters in HTML.

Comment: $string|htmlspecialchars_decode this works for me, for parsing html and showing the data